# Displaying what the Camera can see in a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How would I display what the Camera can see in a view as if you were using the Image Picker in Camera Mode?

Is this possible, to access the camera directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked further…

Check out this question [iPhone: Camera Preview Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001347/iphone-camera-preview-overlay), which provides the below. link to a tutorial on how to do something very similar to my question.

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/archives/821