# How do you create a custom camera view, instead of UIImagePickerViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I created a simple application using UIImagePickerViewController for capturing from the camera, but I'd like to customize the interface for grabbing from the camera, such as adding some buttons.

UIImagePickerViewController doesn't allow this directly, so how would you create a custom view that allows for displaying the live camera feed and capturing from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Camera Preview Overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001347/iphone-camera-preview-overlay)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easy way is to continue to use `UIImagePickerViewController` but set `showsCameraControls` to NO and provide your own user interface using `cameraOverlayView`.

The more difficult (but more flexible) way is to use the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072) classes (particularly `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`) to construct your own camera.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, create a UIImagePickerController from code, adjust its properties, add an overlay onto it, and with you controller, control whatever you want on that overlay : custom controls, overlaying images, etc...

That gives something like this :

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

`OverlayViewController` is the controller that you must write to control everything you add onto the overlay.

`pickerReference` is a property you can keep to send orders to the camera. For example, you could call the following from an IBAction coming from a UIButton placed onto the overlay :

```
[self.pickerReference takePicture];
```

Comment: From my experience, `self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;` `self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;` `self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;` are pointless. These do not change anything. All you need is `self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;`

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the value of showCameraControls to NO and provide your own custom overlay view using the cameraOverlayView.

Comment: @HitendraHckr Why did I copy from which Previous answer ? my answer is the oldest on this page :  Mar 1 '11 at 15:20. I'm not sure how I can copy from a future answer.