# How to force user to use the "square" camera filter when taking a picture

Tags: ios, ios7, camera

I have been looking all over the internet but I cannot find it. Is it possible for my app to leverage the "square" filter in the ios default camera app? Since it has all the functionality I would need (square, and pinch zoom) it would be nice to not have to make my own.I have tried all the different preferences for opening the camera but cannot seem to find it. Is there a library or category on the apple dev site that I might have missed?  Any guidance would help!

Comment: I think you should go with `UIImagePickerViewController` and customize it for your needs. Here are descent answers on how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156417/how-do-you-create-a-custom-camera-view-instead-of-uiimagepickerviewcontroller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073531/iphone-custom-camera-overlay-plus-image-processing-how-to

Comment: put as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go with `UIImagePickerViewController` and customize it for your needs. Here are descent answers on how to use it:

[How do you create a custom camera view, instead of UIImagePickerViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156417/how-do-you-create-a-custom-camera-view-instead-of-uiimagepickerviewcontroller)

... and

[iPhone custom camera overlay (plus image processing) : how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073531/iphone-custom-camera-overlay-plus-image-processing-how-to)

Comment: Great. worked. There are some issues depending on OS but generally works thank you.